# Autocompletion for private NPM package

Tags: javascript, npm, package, babeljs

I am trying to create my own private NPM package. I want to use this package in several other projects of mine. You can imagine it like API library. I use babel for code transpilation.

Let's assume very simple example:

src/index.js

```
class API {
  static testMethod() {
    return null
  }
}

export default API
```

This file gets transpiled using babel: `babel ./src --out-dir ./dist --source-maps`

When I publish this package and install it in another project everything works just fine but IDE shows me warning that API class doesn't have method `testMethod`. I am using WebStorm. I also tried VS Code and it doesn't work either.

My questions are:

- What am I missing?
- Do I need to write JSdoc comments or use Typescript?
- Aren't source maps enough?

WebStorm version 2019.2.4

Error:
[image]

Comment: Hi, there! Can you please post the code that is producing the IDE error? Just to see what your use of the class / import of the module looks like.

Comment: What's your version of WebStorm ?

Comment: Question updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Source maps aren't enough. You need `*.d.ts` definition files to enable autocomplete. I strongly advise you to use typescript. You can find a very brief tutorial here https://cameronnokes.com/blog/the-30-second-guide-to-publishing-a-typescript-package-to-npm/ on how to publish a typescript package with autocomplete

Comment: I believe it's possible without typescript and typescript definition files.

Comment: @Joozty  how, you have any idea?

Comment: Sadly not. I was not able to solve this problem. :(